# Undefined variable error while passing extra variable through Ansible AWX

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I have a playbook to create users, the playbook runs fine when all the three variables are hardcoded whereas if I pass variables I'm getting an error. I executed this playbook through AWX console with extra variables and got "*undefined variable error*"

***Playbook***

```
#User creation playbook
---
- hosts: "all"
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  #vars:
  #  users:
  #  - username: "{{ user }}"
  #    groups: "{{ groups }}"
  #    password: "{{ password }}"
      #replace newpassword with whatever password you want to set for the user
  #  - username: "user2"
  #    groups: "groupC"
  #    password: "{{ 'newpassword' | password_hash('sha512') }}"
  tasks:
  - name: "Create user accounts"
    user:
      name: "{{ username }}"
      groups: "{{ groups }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
      update_password: on_create
    #with_items: "{{ users }}"
  #- name: "Add authorized keys"
  #  authorized_key:
  #    user: "{{ item.username }}"
  #    key: "{{ lookup('file', 'ssh_keys/'+ item.username + '.key.pub') }}"
  #  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

***Extra Vars***

```
---
vars:
 - username: testuserxx
   groups: nginx,mysql
   password: $6$UxUZNNsVnWUSM9ge$0viDFuXUwtLYyx/U4tFmX8w3TknD3C19Oab.clfi67WGGqJUDrkGpMOvHE1zwudXyKl0gmqAw8piR8KFGi55R/
```

I have created password hash using `mkpasswd --method=sha-512`

Below is the error I'm getting

```
fatal: [172.16.12.70]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'password' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/awx_56_skpglhjz/project/user_creation_AWXold.yml': line 17, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - name: \"Create user accounts\"\n    ^ here\n"
}
```

Comment: What is line 17 in the file user_creation_AWXold.yml?

Comment: I removed all the commented lines in the playbook while posting it here. Now updated with the exact playbook. `- name: "Create user accounts"` is the 17th line.

Comment: Can you try removing the hyphen (-) in front of the username variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving quotes for groups and password?

```
groups: 'nginx,mysql'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define your extra vars like this:

```
---
username: testuserxx
groups: nginx,mysql
password: $6$UxUZNNsVnWUSM9ge$0viDFuXUwtLYyx/U4tFmX8w3TknD3C19Oab.clfi67WGGqJUDrkGpMOvHE1zwudXyKl0gmqAw8piR8KFGi55R/
```

Comment: Tried this and got error. `TypeError('%s cannot be converted to a list' % type(value)`.Full traceback can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/suren2306/32b8a594c86cf43bef37260c157b4302)